# Send $POST via URL

Tags: php, html, forms, url, post

Is it possible to send `$_POST` variable via the URL without using a `form` ? or other `"invisible"` type of variable in the `URL`.

**My situation :**

There is a request (from server "ZETA") which calls my php script via the `URL` but this script needs my file name (thats the variable I want to send). 
So I know I can use `$_GET` but I don't want to send the file name in clear in the `URL`.

So is it possible or I'm just wasting my time :p

ps : only html and php, please.

Thx

**Update 1**

This is how I call my script :

```
http://10.13.48.60/XML_MYSQL/xml_to_mysql.php?name=1201072-14913200.xml
```

I just want to make the var "name" invisible when I send.

Comment: You may use `curl`  for that.

Comment: If you're asking can you send GET and POST at the same time, the answer is yes

Comment: You can use [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to make a request with a post body

Comment: Why can't you simply use $_POST?

Comment: @Machavity — You can't. PHP's use of `$_GET` for the query string and `$_POST` for the request body encourages people to wrongly conflate the request method with the place data is stored.

Answer (score 3):

No. PHP will populate `$_GET` with data from the URL and only use the request body to populate `$_POST`.

You can't put unencrypted data in the URL without it being visible to anyone who can see the request (for that matter, you can't put unencrypted data anywhere in the request without it being visible to them).

If you don't want to send the data in the clear, use HTTPS instead of HTTP. This will protect the request from being intercepted (although anyone at either end can still see the data… but since one is creating it and the other is supposed to read it, that should not be a problem).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I will give a try with the solution of cardeol otherwise I will stick with https ^^

Comment: Using POST instead of GET does nothing for security at all.

Comment: its just they don't like when they see the name of the file in clear in the URL

Comment: Tell them to stop applying aesthetic considerations to URLs that aren't going to be printed on paper. It's a waste of their time and yours.

Comment: aight mate I wish I could >< (but you a lil bit off topic :p)

Answer (score -1):

In order to use POST, you will need to use a  tag, and depending on how you are pulling up these URLs, it could be easier to use javascript to help out. Here's a basic example:

```
<form method="post" action="data.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="parameter" value="1234" />
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

The Go button would POST the form data, and now in data.php you will be able to retrieve the value from $_POST['parameter']. Note that when using POST, you will probably want to redirect (HTTP 302) back to a page so that when a user hits the back button, the browser doesn't prompt to resubmit the form.

Using javascript, you could set the parameter input to a different value before posting the form.